# Where is the setting for automatically adding " in html-attributes in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

If I try to write `<a href="https://puggan.se/">puggan</a>` in a html-dockument in PhpStorm, it ends up as: `<a href=""https:/>/puggan.se/">puggan</a>`

The problem is that when I add the `=` after `href`, it automatically adds two quotes `"`, and places the cursor between them, and when I write the `"` myself (as I'm used to do), its overwrites the 2nd `"`, and the cursor ends up behinds them, and the attribute value ends up outside the `"`.

- Where is the setting for turning this off?
- Dose it have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Smart Keys`
3. Disable `XML/HTML | Add quotes for attribute value on typing '=' and attribute completion` option

[image]

Comment: P.S. You may also be interested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18966 ticket -- it's about adding quotes but "skipping them" if typed manually (to prevent the behaviour you have described).